# Loading Raster using QGIS API in Windows

Tags: qgis, raster, c++

I am trying to develop a C++ application using QGIS. I have to load a tif file and show it. 
First I wrote an app similar to samples on the internet. It works on Linux, but it does not work on Windows. I compiled QGIS libraries myself using VS2008 and also tried binaries downloaded using Osgeo4w installer.

The app loads the plugins and displays the canvas, but cannot paint the raster layer on it. So I just can see a blank white canvas window.

The debug output says "Layer not found in registry", however I do add it to registry as follows:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(myRasterLayer, TRUE);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked if the layer `isValid()`?

Comment: yes. the layer is valid.

Comment: I printed the address of QgsMapLayerRegistry instance at the beginning of my code and also inside QgsMapLayerRegistry constructor. Two addresses are different. How can a singleton object have a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Found it!

In Linux, CORE_EXPORT and GUI_EXPORT macros should be set empty,

However in Windows you should define them in .pro file as follows:

```
DEFINES +=  CORE_EXPORT="__declspec(dllimport)"
DEFINES +=  GUI_EXPORT="__declspec(dllimport)"
```